# is_dir returning false on symlinks in apache

Tags: php, apache, macos, symlink, osx-lion

I run a third party PHP application on my local AMP stack on my Mac. I recently bought a new Mac Mini with Lion, and am trying to set it up. My previous computer was a MB air with MAMP. Now I'm using the built-in apache/php and a homebrew installed MySQL.

Here's my problem: I have a directory with symbolic links. These symlinks are to directories, and the PHP application is checking these with `is_dir()`.

On my Lion AMP setup, this `is_dir()` is failing. The same setup on my Snow Leopard MAMP `is_dir()` works fine with my symlinks.

Here's where it gets more curious. If I do `php -a` (php interactive command line mode), and do `is_dir()` on the very same directories, it returns true. It only returns false in the context of an apache request. This makes me think it has something to do with the apache user (which is `_www`) not being able to access the symlinks. Troubleshooting this falls outside of my expertise.

Other notes:

1. Yes, I have `FollowSymLinks` turned on in my apache config, and in
   fact, the directory where the symlinks in question reside is a
   symlink itself. Apache has no problem with it. Until PHP `is_dir()` is
   used.
2. No, I cannot edit the PHP application and just fall back on `is_link()`
   and `readlink()`.
3. This exact same setup worked on my Snow Leopard/MAMP setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't symlinks still considered files until you actually recurse into them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah saw your comment on changing them to `777` but still wondering why it's not working.
My solution below might not help you.

EDIT:

If you have access to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, 
edit it via `sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.
Then change these 1 of these lines or both of them

```
User _www
Group _www
```

Here is an example of my directory listing.

```
ace:remote-app ace (git::master)$ ls -al
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  24 ace  staff   816  7 Aug 00:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 ace  staff   374  4 Aug 13:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 ace  staff   102 12 Jul 17:06 .bundle
drwxr-xr-x  14 ace  staff   476  7 Aug 02:29 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 ace  staff   100  1 Aug 19:20 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 ace  staff     9  1 Aug 19:20 .rspec
drwxrwxr-x  10 ace  staff   340 14 Jul 15:58 public
```

Now my public directory has `775` permissions, meaning `owner` and `group` have full permissions while other users can only read and execute.
It depends if you want apache user to become `ace` from the default `_www` or the apache group to become `staff` from the default `_www`.

Once you've decided on which to change, restart apache.

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
```

And your page should now have access to the directories / files.
One thing to note is that you have to change ownership for files that have been already been written by your webpage as those have `_www:_www` ownership and you won't have access to them after the restart.
You can change their new ownership through this, `-R` is to make it recursive.

```
sudo chown -R newapacheuser:newapachegroup <path>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I changed the user and group in httpd.conf to my username and group. Not totally ideal, but it's just for my local development so I can live with it. I'm still not sure why setting things to 777 didn't make it so _www user had access, but I'm just gonna move on and quit fiddling with this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check permissions/owner?

From the PHP manual: Note: The results of this function are cached.

Comment: i changed permissions on those symlinks and their associated dirs to 777. That should be enough, no?

Comment: Maybe there is a difference in php.ini for CGI and command line setups. Also above CGI there is Apache. If from CLI works and from CGI doesn't then I presume there is a configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I created the following link:

```
cd /home/mike/uploads
ln -s ./data /sites/www.test.com/docroot/data
```

Then I created a test.php file in /sites/www.test.com/docroot that just did the following:

```
$dir = "/sites/www.test.com/docroot/data";
"is_dir\t\t" .is_dir($dir) ."\n";
```

When I ran test.php from the command line, it would show up as is_dir was True, but when I loaded test.php from a browser through apache, it was False.

I went to /sites/www.test.com/docroot/data and did a

```
chmod -R 755 .
```

That didn't change anything. Then I realized, the **parent** to the actual symlinked dir needed proper permissions set (/home/mike/uploads). I did a chmod on that dir, and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check open_basedir directive in php config. That path should also be included.
In linux, you can list multiple folders by separating them with a colon.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir